# How to select from a master table but replace certain rows using a secondary, linked table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables with a foreign key relationship on an ID. I'll refer to them as master and secondary to make things easier and also not worry about the FK for now. Here is cut down, easy to reproduce example  using table variables to represent the problem:

```
DECLARE @Master TABLE (
    [MasterID] Uniqueidentifier NOT NULL
    ,[Description] NVARCHAR(50)
)
DECLARE @Secondary TABLE (
    [SecondaryID] Uniqueidentifier NOT NULL
    ,[MasterID] Uniqueidentifier NOT NULL
    ,[OtherInfo] NVARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO @Master ([MasterID], [Description])
VALUES ('0C1F1A0C-1DB5-4FA2-BC70-26AA9B10D5C3', 'Test')
,('2696ECD2-FFDB-4E26-83D0-F146ED419C9C', 'Test 2')
,('F21568F0-59C5-4950-B936-AA73DA6009B5', 'Test 3')
INSERT INTO @Secondary (SecondaryID, MasterID, Otherinfo)
VALUES ('514673A6-8B5C-429B-905F-15BD8B55CB5D','0C1F1A0C-1DB5-4FA2-BC70-26AA9B10D5C3','Other info')

SELECT [MasterID], [Description], NULL AS [OtherInfo] FROM @Master
UNION
SELECT S.[MasterID], M.[Description], [OtherInfo] FROM @Secondary S
JOIN @Master M ON M.MasterID = S.MasterID
```

With the results.....

```
0C1F1A0C-1DB5-4FA2-BC70-26AA9B10D5C3    Test    NULL
0C1F1A0C-1DB5-4FA2-BC70-26AA9B10D5C3    Test    Other info
F21568F0-59C5-4950-B936-AA73DA6009B5    Test 3  NULL
2696ECD2-FFDB-4E26-83D0-F146ED419C9C    Test 2  NULL
```

.... I would like to only return records from `@Secondary` if there is a duplicate `MasterID`, so this is my expected output:

```
0C1F1A0C-1DB5-4FA2-BC70-26AA9B10D5C3    Test    Other info
F21568F0-59C5-4950-B936-AA73DA6009B5    Test 3  NULL
2696ECD2-FFDB-4E26-83D0-F146ED419C9C    Test 2  NULL
```

I tried inserting my union query into a temporary table, then using a CTE with the partition function. This kind of works but unfortunately returns the row from the `@Master` table rather than the `@Secondary` table (regardless of the order I select). See below.

```
DECLARE @Results TABLE (MasterID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,[Description] NVARCHAR(50),OtherInfo NVARCHAR(50))
INSERT INTO @Results
SELECT [MasterID], [Description], NULL AS [OtherInfo] FROM @Master
UNION
SELECT S.[MasterID], M.[Description], [OtherInfo] FROM @Secondary S
JOIN @Master M ON M.MasterID = S.MasterID

;WITH CTE AS (
SELECT *, RN= ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [MasterID] ORDER BY [Description] DESC) FROM @Results
)
SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE RN =1
```

Results:

```
0C1F1A0C-1DB5-4FA2-BC70-26AA9B10D5C3    Test    NULL    1
F21568F0-59C5-4950-B936-AA73DA6009B5    Test 3  NULL    1
2696ECD2-FFDB-4E26-83D0-F146ED419C9C    Test 2  NULL    1
```

Note that I am not just trying to select the rows which have a value for `OtherInfo`, this is just to help differentiate the two tables in the result set.

Just to reiterate, what I need to only return the rows present in `@Secondary`, when there is a duplicate `MasterID`. If `@Secondary` has a row for a particular `MasterID`, I don't need the row from `@Master`. I hope this makes sense.

What is the best way to do this? I am happy to redesign my database structure. I'm effectively trying to have a master list of items but sometimes take one of those and assign extra info  to it + tie it to another ID. In this instance, that record replaces the master list.

Comment: I'm a little lost on how one row in `secondary` can have a duplicate master id.

Comment: Your `UNION` query first returns ***all*** the rows from the table `@Master`, then it returns all the rows where the `JOIN` is successful. As a result `0C1F1A0C-1DB5-4FA2-BC70-26AA9B10D5C3` is returned twice, as it is both in `@Master` and fulfils the `JOIN`. Perhaps you're after a `LEFT JOIN` and not `UNION`? A `UNION` returns the distinct rows from the datasets that are "unioned". if you run those 2 SQL Statement, you get 3 and 1 rows respectively, all of which are different, so 4 rows in the final result set makes perfect sense.

Comment: @GordonLinoff The secondary table has its own ID as a PK. It can then have as many duplicate masterIDs as it wants. I'm trying to have a master list of say, 10 things, then allow any of those to be added to the secondary table against another ID. Think of master document templates, then some copies which are bespoke. A bit like inheritance.

Comment: @Larnu I tried various joins but still didn't get the desired results. The Union is so that I can get results from both tables. I just want to drop any that come from `master` if the same masterid appears in `secondary`. Also please look at the final part where i have attempted to fix the resultset with a cte

Comment: What about a `LEFT JOIN` didn't work? It seems to work fine: [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2ac9a1e2fa66e7da58b18a1dd7483c7c)

Comment: It doesn't work in my actual tables though. I will repost the question shortly with the real data. I was hoping I could get away with this test example but it doesn't seem to match up exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are *way* overcomplicating this. All you need is a left join.

```
SELECT M.[MasterID], M.[Description], S.[OtherInfo] FROM @Master M
LEFT JOIN @Secondary S ON M.MasterID = S.MasterID
```

Answer (score 1):

Union seems to be the wrong approach... I would suggest a left join:

```
SELECT m.[MasterID], m.[Description], s.[OtherInfo]
  FROM @Master m
  LEFT JOIN @Secondary s ON s.MasterID = m.MasterID
```